# MATLAB code to detect the corners of an object without using the built in functions

Tags: matlab, edge-detection, corners

I need to write a MATLAB code to detect the corners of an object in a black and white image without the built-in MATLAB vision toolbox or bwlabel, imrotate, imresize, corner, edge, reshape, imfilter,regionprops or imfill.

I have used the Sobel gradient filter to detect the edges of the object.

I now want to detect the corners of the object without using the built in corner function in MATLAB

[image]

Comment: Questions requesting working code written to a specification are off-topic as they are unlikely to benefit anyone else. Instead, describe the problem you're solving and where you're stuck.

Comment: You can intersect the edges

Comment: and even if your edges were curves, you can find corners where there are discontinuities or extremely immediate changes in the angle.